# What are some alternative ways to represent the golden ratio?

Tags: soft-question, irrational-numbers, golden-ratio

What are some alternative ways to represent the golden ratio? I already know the relatively boring ones compared to the complex ones as well as:

- $\displaystyle \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2},$
- $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+}} \dots},$
- $\displaystyle \phi + 1 = \phi ^{-1},$

and also the multiplier of consecutive Fibonacci terms. As some current answers have given, I would **not** like any formulas that reproduce the above. They are **not** classed as interesting, as they include repetition. I am looking for formulas that are interesting, and I am hoping to find some without repetition.

Comment: I think your first number is not the same as the others. I think you want $(\sqrt5-1)/2$.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "good." I like $\phi^2-\phi -1=0,$ or equivalently $\phi - 1 = \phi ^{-1}$ (check your equations). Rather than boring, I consider it elegant.

Comment: So, Goodra, any thoughts about any of the answers you have recieved?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes, but not every question requires accepting immediately. I'm not sure whether that question originates from moderating or just looking at your profile, but questions like this I personally believe that a period of time (approx. 2 weeks) should pass before deciding. Sorry if I misunderstood you intentions...

Comment: No need to accept anything in a hurry, or ever, but there are three answers, and not even one of them has an upvote. Upvote just means, "this answer is useful". Are all the answers useless?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't know really. I have a neutral opinion.

Comment: OK, Vortex, two weeks expired a year-and-a-half ago. Still undecided?

Comment: @GerryMyerson oof sorry... I completely forgot about SE... I've had other interested recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) gives $$\phi=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}$$ $\phi=1+2\sin(\pi/10)$, $\phi=2\cos(\pi/5)$, $\phi=\lim_{n\to\infty}(F(n+1)/F(n))$ where $F(n)$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number, and others.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple

- $$
   \phi = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{F_k F_{k + 1}}
   $$
- $$
   \phi = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \cdots}}}
   $$
- Define the [alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) $\{0,1\}$ with the production rules $0\to 01$ and $1 \to 0$

You get

$$
0 \to 01 \to 010 \to \cdots
$$

the locations of the ones occur at locations $\lfloor k\phi \rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few more...

$$
\begin{align}
\varphi
&=\sqrt{1+\varphi}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\varphi}}\\
&=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\varphi}}}=\cdots
\end{align}
$$

as well as

$$
\varphi=1+\frac{1}{\varphi}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\varphi}}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\varphi}}}=\cdots
$$

and

$$
\sqrt[3]{1+2\sqrt[3]{1+2\sqrt[3]{1+2\sqrt[3]{1+2\sqrt[3]{\cdots}}}}}\to\varphi
$$

And just for kicks, let's call attention to the golden sequence

$$\cdots ,\frac{1}{\varphi^3},\frac{1}{\varphi^2},\frac{1}{\varphi^1},1,\varphi^1,\varphi^2,\varphi^3,\cdots$$

**UPDATE**

Here is a genralization of the *root* forms

$$
\sqrt[n]{F_{n-1}+F_n\sqrt[n]{F_{n-1}+F_n\sqrt[n]{F_{n-1}+F_n\sqrt[n]{F_{n-1}+F_n\sqrt[n]{\cdots}}}}}\to\varphi
$$

where $F_n$ is the Fibonacci number.